# How to select multiple avg from the same table in sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I am trying to select the average rating of the title using 1 table I've tried CASE WHEN  its not working when  I use CASE WHEN its returning all the averages but i need it to return only the selected from the user thats selected

`ID                  USERNAME         TITLE          RATING   RATED_BY`

```
1                   tommy           Bigbear          5       oscar

2                   tommy           Bigbear          2       dillan

3                   tommy           HardLife         3       jeff

4                   benben          Bigbear          9       mike
```

my database is called game_ratings

```
$rates_select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT rating AS rates,
       CASE WHEN title ='Bigbear' THEN AVG(rating) ELSE NULL END AS bigbear,
       CASE WHEN title ='HardLife' THEN AVG(rating) ELSE NULL END AS hardlife
       FROM game_ratings WHERE username='tommy'") ;

    if($rate_select  > 0){

      $rate = mysqli_fetch_array($rate_select) ;
      $rate_bigbear = $rate['bigbear'] ;
      $rate_hardlife = $rate['hardlife'] ;

     echo $rate_bigbear ; 
    }
```

this is returning the avg total of all tommys ratings  not just big bear 
if i echo $rate_hardlife i want it to give me that avg if i echo $rate_bigbear i want it to give me that avg for tommy

Comment: Why not simply use `SELECT title, AVG(rating) AS rating FROM game_ratings WHERE username='tommy' GROUP BY title`?

Comment: how do i output the individual title rating doing it this way , i was confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would have the `CASE` as an argument to `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN title = 'Bigbear' THEN rating END) AS bigbear,
       AVG(CASE WHEN title = 'HardLife' THEN rating END) AS hardlife
FROM game_ratings
WHERE username = 'tommy';
```

Of course, it would seem simpler to write:

```
SELECT title, AVG(rating) as rating
FROM game_ratings
WHERE username = 'tommy' AND
      title  IN ('Bigbear', 'HardLife')
GROUP BY title;
```

But this returns the values on two rows.

Comment: how do I get the individual rates based on title using the simple way that mark suggested ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `AVG` ignores nulls like other aggregate functions, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN title = 'Bigbear' THEN rating ELSE NULL END) AS bigbear
, AVG(CASE WHEN title = 'HardLife' THEN rating ELSE NULL END) AS hardlife
FROM game_ratings
WHERE username = 'tommy'
;
```

Note that I omitted the `ratings` part of `SELECT ratings`; it just doesn't make sense to include that field in the query results (you'd get an effectively random value from the rows inspected.)

Also, you're probably much better off doing as Mark Baker's comment suggests; results from the query he suggested would automatically include average ratings for new titles automatically.